# Tampermonkey, Adding parameters to the end of an URL using script

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, parameters, userscripts

As the title states, i would like to write a script to add certain parameter to the existing url in the address bar of a browser.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name RDS
// @version 1
// @grant none
// @include *://webdocument.*/file/*
// @exclude *://webdocument.*/file/*&hsequence*
// ==/UserScript==

if (webLink.indexOf("webdocument") > -1) {
document.location.href = document.location.href + "&hsegment=2";
}
```

But it's not giving me the results i want. It does works but the redirection time is almost 10 seconds. Most of the time the script doesn't work at all. Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

All i want is to add "&hsegment=2" to the end of URL when http://webdocument.com/file/* is entered. So the output url should be like http://webdocument.com/file/*&hsegment=2

Comment: `It does works but the redirection time is almost 10 seconds` Sounds like a problem with the *site*, and not with your script. Try `// @run-at        document-start`

Comment: I tested with other sites too but still not working... don't know what am i doing wrong...

Comment: See the duplicates. Also the question script has several errors. (`&hsequence`, `webLink`, `@run-at`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a million... the script works flawlessly..